# GridView title and date orientation

Tags: java, android, xml

I want my title and date text views to appear at the bottom of the image instead of the top where they currently are. I want them to overlap the image like they are at the moment but then have the title then date underneath with the same background so they appear to be in the same "box"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#55000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<uk.ac.kent.sc580.edanews.GridViewItem
    android:id="@+id/listImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="#3183b9"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RelativeLayout` instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#55000000">

    <uk.ac.kent.sc580.edanews.GridViewItem
        android:id="@+id/listImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, it's asking me to specify an orientation on LinearLayout?